# Docker on php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed error proposed to run mysql_upgrade . But no such command

Tags: docker

Running my laravel app uder docker I got error :
`SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service` not known

Checking logs I Found first error

```
Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
```

with full logs output.

```
$ docker logs --tail=100  -t  hostels3_db 
2020-11-23T16:03:07.260203400Z 2020-11-23 18:03:07+02:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 5.7.28-1debian9 started.
2020-11-23T16:03:07.538929417Z 2020-11-23T16:03:07.532079Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2020-11-23T16:03:07.538967316Z 2020-11-23T16:03:07.536115Z 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.7.28) starting as process 1 ...
2020-11-23T16:03:07.540164360Z 2020-11-23T16:03:07.540038Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2020-11-23T16:03:07.540196758Z 2020-11-23T16:03:07.540067Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2020-11-23T16:03:07.540205811Z 2020-11-23T16:03:07.540071Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-11-23T16:03:07.540211561Z 2020-11-23T16:03:07.540074Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2020-11-23T16:03:07.540217415Z 2020-11-23T16:03:07.540077Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-11-23T16:03:07.540222860Z 2020-11-23T16:03:07.540079Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2020-11-23T16:03:07.540387428Z 2020-11-23T16:03:07.540351Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-11-23T16:03:07.540488414Z 2020-11-23T16:03:07.540445Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2020-11-23T16:03:07.542310813Z 2020-11-23T16:03:07.542186Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2020-11-23T16:03:07.553357147Z 2020-11-23T16:03:07.553261Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-11-23T16:03:07.555303642Z 2020-11-23T16:03:07.555235Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2020-11-23T16:03:07.568860380Z 2020-11-23T16:03:07.568738Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2020-11-23T16:03:07.584405576Z 2020-11-23T16:03:07.584248Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-11-23T16:03:07.584972764Z 2020-11-23T16:03:07.584831Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-11-23T16:03:07.717029605Z 2020-11-23T16:03:07.716921Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-11-23T16:03:07.718077401Z 2020-11-23T16:03:07.717997Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2020-11-23T16:03:07.718094783Z 2020-11-23T16:03:07.718014Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2020-11-23T16:03:07.718763420Z 2020-11-23T16:03:07.718548Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.28 started; log sequence number 1210642
2020-11-23T16:03:07.719005171Z 2020-11-23T16:03:07.718930Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2020-11-23T16:03:07.719111494Z 2020-11-23T16:03:07.719037Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2020-11-23T16:03:07.719281358Z mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
2020-11-23T16:03:07.719297641Z 2020-11-23T16:03:07.719239Z 0 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
2020-11-23T16:03:07.719462936Z 2020-11-23T16:03:07.719405Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 201123 18:03:07
2020-11-23T16:03:07.719774854Z 2020-11-23T16:03:07.719706Z 0 [Warning] World-writable config file './auto.cnf' is ignored.
2020-11-23T16:03:07.719995798Z 2020-11-23T16:03:07.719937Z 0 [Warning] World-writable config file './auto.cnf' has been removed.
2020-11-23T16:03:07.720010688Z 
2020-11-23T16:03:07.720164804Z 2020-11-23T16:03:07.720040Z 0 [Note] Salting uuid generator variables, current_pid: 1, server_start_time: 1606147387, bytes_sent: 0, 
2020-11-23T16:03:07.720174796Z 2020-11-23T16:03:07.720097Z 0 [Note] Generated uuid: '6086503a-2da5-11eb-9817-0242ac120003', server_start_time: 281476582858044, bytes_sent: 94516959456608
2020-11-23T16:03:07.720178722Z 2020-11-23T16:03:07.720116Z 0 [Warning] No existing UUID has been found, so we assume that this is the first time that this server has been started. Generating a new UUID: 6086503a-2da5-11eb-9817-0242ac120003.
2020-11-23T16:03:07.725984855Z 2020-11-23T16:03:07.725874Z 0 [Warning] Gtid table is not ready to be used. Table 'mysql.gtid_executed' cannot be opened.
2020-11-23T16:03:07.727984235Z 2020-11-23T16:03:07.727862Z 0 [Note] Found ca.pem, server-cert.pem and server-key.pem in data directory. Trying to enable SSL support using them.
2020-11-23T16:03:07.728022269Z 2020-11-23T16:03:07.727893Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of SSL certificates as certificate files are present in data directory.
2020-11-23T16:03:07.729638604Z 2020-11-23T16:03:07.729544Z 0 [Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2020-11-23T16:03:07.729745262Z 2020-11-23T16:03:07.729657Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of RSA key pair as key files are present in data directory.
2020-11-23T16:03:07.730730336Z 2020-11-23T16:03:07.730578Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2020-11-23T16:03:07.730769798Z 2020-11-23T16:03:07.730635Z 0 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2020-11-23T16:03:07.730883889Z 2020-11-23T16:03:07.730660Z 0 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2020-11-23T16:03:07.730928762Z 2020-11-23T16:03:07.730725Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2020-11-23T16:03:07.752259553Z 2020-11-23T16:03:07.752127Z 0 [Warning] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2020-11-23T16:03:07.752453539Z 2020-11-23T16:03:07.752409Z 0 [Warning] Failed to open optimizer cost constant tables
2020-11-23T16:03:07.752466059Z 
2020-11-23T16:03:07.752651518Z 2020-11-23T16:03:07.752609Z 0 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exist
2020-11-23T16:03:07.752658415Z 2020-11-23T16:03:07.752626Z 0 [ERROR] Fatal error: Failed to initialize ACL/grant/time zones structures or failed to remove temporary table files.
2020-11-23T16:03:07.752757432Z 2020-11-23T16:03:07.752708Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
2020-11-23T16:03:07.752766967Z 
2020-11-23T16:03:07.752852281Z 2020-11-23T16:03:07.752820Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2020-11-23T16:03:07.752903598Z 2020-11-23T16:03:07.752863Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ngram'
2020-11-23T16:03:07.752911673Z 2020-11-23T16:03:07.752869Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2020-11-23T16:03:07.752916418Z 2020-11-23T16:03:07.752872Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2020-11-23T16:03:07.752920525Z 2020-11-23T16:03:07.752876Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2020-11-23T16:03:07.752923490Z 2020-11-23T16:03:07.752880Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2020-11-23T16:03:07.753014481Z 2020-11-23T16:03:07.752972Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2020-11-23T16:03:07.753025991Z 2020-11-23T16:03:07.752977Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2020-11-23T16:03:07.753031232Z 2020-11-23T16:03:07.752992Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_VIRTUAL'
2020-11-23T16:03:07.753035755Z 2020-11-23T16:03:07.753002Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2020-11-23T16:03:07.753040217Z 2020-11-23T16:03:07.753005Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2020-11-23T16:03:07.753059246Z 2020-11-23T16:03:07.753008Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2020-11-23T16:03:07.753064177Z 2020-11-23T16:03:07.753011Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2020-11-23T16:03:07.753068482Z 2020-11-23T16:03:07.753014Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2020-11-23T16:03:07.753072952Z 2020-11-23T16:03:07.753017Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2020-11-23T16:03:07.753077250Z 2020-11-23T16:03:07.753019Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2020-11-23T16:03:07.753081787Z 2020-11-23T16:03:07.753022Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2020-11-23T16:03:07.753095582Z 2020-11-23T16:03:07.753025Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2020-11-23T16:03:07.753099666Z 2020-11-23T16:03:07.753028Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2020-11-23T16:03:07.753103029Z 2020-11-23T16:03:07.753031Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2020-11-23T16:03:07.753106459Z 2020-11-23T16:03:07.753034Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2020-11-23T16:03:07.753109996Z 2020-11-23T16:03:07.753037Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2020-11-23T16:03:07.753113807Z 2020-11-23T16:03:07.753040Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2020-11-23T16:03:07.753117826Z 2020-11-23T16:03:07.753043Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2020-11-23T16:03:07.753121623Z 2020-11-23T16:03:07.753046Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2020-11-23T16:03:07.753124800Z 2020-11-23T16:03:07.753049Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TEMP_TABLE_INFO'
2020-11-23T16:03:07.753127370Z 2020-11-23T16:03:07.753052Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2020-11-23T16:03:07.753136537Z 2020-11-23T16:03:07.753055Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2020-11-23T16:03:07.753143638Z 2020-11-23T16:03:07.753058Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2020-11-23T16:03:07.753149405Z 2020-11-23T16:03:07.753061Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2020-11-23T16:03:07.753152303Z 2020-11-23T16:03:07.753064Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2020-11-23T16:03:07.753154724Z 2020-11-23T16:03:07.753066Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2020-11-23T16:03:07.753157147Z 2020-11-23T16:03:07.753070Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2020-11-23T16:03:07.753159551Z 2020-11-23T16:03:07.753073Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2020-11-23T16:03:07.753161970Z 2020-11-23T16:03:07.753076Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2020-11-23T16:03:07.753164380Z 2020-11-23T16:03:07.753079Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2020-11-23T16:03:07.753166768Z 2020-11-23T16:03:07.753082Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2020-11-23T16:03:07.753169166Z 2020-11-23T16:03:07.753085Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2020-11-23T16:03:07.753171586Z 2020-11-23T16:03:07.753088Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'InnoDB'
2020-11-23T16:03:07.753273312Z 2020-11-23T16:03:07.753162Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2020-11-23T16:03:07.753281815Z 2020-11-23T16:03:07.753212Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2020-11-23T16:03:07.853905700Z 2020-11-23T16:03:07.853729Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2020-11-23T16:03:07.854636071Z 2020-11-23T16:03:07.854526Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 201123 18:03:07
2020-11-23T16:03:09.374224235Z 2020-11-23T16:03:09.374057Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1210661
2020-11-23T16:03:09.376501037Z 2020-11-23T16:03:09.376365Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2020-11-23T16:03:09.376534030Z 2020-11-23T16:03:09.376403Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2020-11-23T16:03:09.376540517Z 2020-11-23T16:03:09.376416Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2020-11-23T16:03:09.376546062Z 2020-11-23T16:03:09.376424Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2020-11-23T16:03:09.376551251Z 2020-11-23T16:03:09.376462Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2020-11-23T16:03:09.376756634Z 2020-11-23T16:03:09.376680Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2020-11-23T16:03:09.378631194Z 2020-11-23T16:03:09.378529Z 0 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
2020-11-23T16:03:09.378653320Z
```

I tried to run under bash :

```
root@91e8a98f2e63:/var/www/hostels3_docker_root# uname -a
Linux 91e8a98f2e63 4.15.0-121-generic #123-Ubuntu SMP Mon Oct 5 16:16:40 UTC 2020 x86_64 GNU/Linux

root@91e8a98f2e63:/var/www/hostels3_docker_root# mysql_upgrade
bash: mysql_upgrade: command not found
```

Not sure which steps have I to take ?

My __DOCKER/docker-compose.yml :

```
version: '3.5'

services:


    web:
        container_name: hostels3_web

        build:
            context: ./web
            dockerfile: Dockerfile.yml

        environment:
            - APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
        volumes:
            - ${APP_PATH_HOST}:${APP_PTH_CONTAINER}
        ports:
            - 8084:80
        working_dir: ${APP_PTH_CONTAINER}


    db:
        container_name: hostels3_db
        image: mysql:5.7.28
        restart: always
        environment:
            - MYSQL_DATABASE=DockerHostels3
            - MYSQL_USER=docker_user
            - MYSQL_PASSWORD=4321
            - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=false
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=321
            - TZ=Europe/Kiev

        volumes:
            - ${DB_PATH_HOST}:/var/lib/mysql


    adminer:
      container_name: hostels3_adminer
      image: adminer
      restart: always
      ports:
        - 8085:8080
      links:
        - db


    composer:
        container_name: hostels3_composer
        image: composer:1.8
        volumes:
            - ${APP_PATH_HOST}:${APP_PTH_CONTAINER}
        working_dir: ${APP_PTH_CONTAINER}
        command: composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

__DOCKER/web/Dockerfile.yml :

```
FROM php:7.3-apache

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
    python \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libwebp-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    nano \
    mc \
    git-core \

#    libmagickwand-dev --no-install-recommends && \
#    pecl install imagick && imagick && \
#    docker-php-ext-enable imagick && \

    curl \
    build-essential \
    openssl \
    libssl-dev \
    libgmp-dev \
    libldap2-dev \
    netcat \
    locate \
    # composer \
    && git clone https://github.com/nodejs/node.git && \
  cd node  \
  && git checkout v12.0.0 \
  && ./configure \
  && make \
  && make install

  RUN npm install cross-env

  RUN npm install -g yarn

  RUN  docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-webp-dir=/usr/include/  --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/


  # Install Composer
  RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

  RUN  docker-php-ext-install gd pdo pdo_mysql zip gmp bcmath pcntl ldap sysvmsg exif  \
&& a2enmod rewrite

  # RUN install-php-extensions imagick

COPY virtualhost.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
```

How to fix it ?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know about docker but you have multiple errors in the mysql startup, all related to table opening, maybe the daemon does not have write access to the filesystem?

Comment: In which way can I add access ? You see all the system works I do not see any errors more, only this. This is actually working project I did not work wityh several last months and restarted OS sincse last workin with it